# Very bad nfs / cifs performance

Tags: linux, nfs, network-attached-storage, scp, cifs

I mount a NAS under Ubuntu Linux 10.04.

Unfortunately I get a very bad read/write performance, although I played around with various options (I have to admit that I do not really know what to do there - I just altered the buffer sizes and such).

I found some hints that the Linux `cifs-client` is known to be somehow problematic. But using *nfs-common* rather than *cifs* gives similar results in terms of performance.

The strange thing is: When I try a secure-copy (`scp`), everything works fine. Unfortunately, secure login is only allowed for the admin of the NAS - so this is no option for daily use :(.

Edit:
I tried mounting with and without the *async* option and tested the troughput for different sized blocks. Here are some benchmark results:

with `/etc/fstab`

```
xxx.xx.xx.xx:Share  /media/Share       nfs    rw,nodev,relatime,vers=3,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,mountvers=3,mountproto=tcp   0       0
```

`dd` tells me:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/media/Share/bigfile bs=1M count=20
20+0 Datensätze ein
20+0 Datensätze aus
20971520 Bytes (21 MB) kopiert, 33,4046 s, 628 kB/s

dd if=/dev/zero of=/media/Share/bigfile bs=1k count=2000
2000+0 Datensätze ein
2000+0 Datensätze aus
2048000 Bytes (2,0 MB) kopiert, 3,60063 s, 569 kB/s
```

with `/etc/fstab`

```
xxx.xx.xx.xx:Share  /media/Share       nfs    rw,nodev,relatime,vers=3,rsize=8192,wsize=8192,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,mountvers=3,mountproto=tcp,async   0       0
```

`dd` tells me:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/media/Share/bigfile bs=1M count=20
20+0 Datensätze ein
20+0 Datensätze aus
20971520 Bytes (21 MB) kopiert, 34,2046 s, 613 kB/s

dd if=/dev/zero of=/media/Share/bigfile bs=1k count=2000
2000+0 Datensätze ein
2000+0 Datensätze aus
2048000 Bytes (2,0 MB) kopiert, 3,79684 s, 539 kB/s
```

Edit: I tried to access another NAS in the network with very similar results. So it seems the problem is really at my client system.

I am grateful for any hints to solve this issue.

Comment: What happens if you try your dd with larger blocksizes? Like 1M?

Comment: I tried that and unfortunately the write speed is more or less the same, see above - I edited my initial post.

Comment: What kind of network setup you have? At my home network NAS mounted over WLAN is ridiculously slow when I use NFS or Samba, but FTP or scp works for me fast enough.

Comment: It's a Gigabit Ethernet network in principle, although it is huge and unfortunately I do not have deeper insight in the whole structure (it's at a company). Do you know the reason for the behavior you see with your WLAN NAS?

Comment: How are things if you try UDP? Is there another NAS somewhere in the network that you can also test to?

Comment: I have to admit that I don't know how to access it via UDP (I do not see that UDP is supported directly by the NAS - it's a Qnas Turbo NAS). I forgot to mention that I tried accessing another NAS in the network with the same results, so obviously it's really my client causing trouble :(.

Comment: @Jakob: Can you copy data fast anywhere in your company via NFS/Samba? Is there something else than NAS devices available that would use NFS/Samba?

Comment: Copying from/to/between Windows clients and NAS works seamless (all via smb shares).

Answer (score 1):

The usual suspect would be synchronous write. Try mounting the NFS with async option.

I've never played with this big wsize and rsize. Try something about 8k and see if it maybe helps you.

**Edit:**

Can you verify on the NAS, that it's exporting the filesystem with async option?

I would also try different option, starting with reducing their number:

```
rw,hard,async
rw,hard,async,rsize=8192,wsize=8192
rw,hard,async,rsize=8192,wsize=8192,vers=3
rw,hard,async,rsize=8192,wsize=8192,vers=3,relatime
...
```

etc

Can you log in to the NAS and monitor its performance too? One case I encountered was a NAS spawning multiple NFS daemons and dying under the load when a client connected.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to mount with smaller block sizes and the _async_ option (which is default anyway as far as I understand the manpage). `dd` gives more or less equal results for this case - I edited my initial question accordingly.
Any more ideas?